# IIS with secure socket connection keeps responding after stopping website

Tags: asp.net, iis, websocket, signalr, .net-4.7.2

I'm running IIS 10.0 on Windows Server 2019 Standard a simple ASP.NET Framework 4.7.2 with long running Websocket connection and SignalR.

Things work well when it comes to stopping the website and sockets are closed if I'm using non secured sockets. However if I have a secure socket connection (TLS/SSL) the worker process will hang as long as the sockets are open. The client will continue to send and receive responses from the server. The only way to fix this is to have the client restart the connection.

Both direct websockets or via SignalR will cause this issue, the application will keep on running after trying to stop the website, transmitting and receiving messages over the secure socket; as soon as the socket closes the worker process dies as expected.

Here is a similar issue with no response : [Server keeps sending ping messages to client after IIS site is stopped.](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4382)

Connections do not timeout after the app pool timeout (90s)

Here is a screenshot of the active connections
[image]

What could be causing this and how do I make sure these connections are dropped when a stop/recycle is requested by IIS ?

**Update:**
If I change the port but still use a secure connection, the problem goes away. On website stop, the connections are dropped and the worker process dies as expected. So it seems to have something to do with port 443...

Comment: Try troubleshooting with [Failed Request Tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) or [PerfView](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567). Both tools can monitor passively and trigger log collection on requests that take longer than the time specified.